# Paypal IPN Integration into PHP

Tags: php, curl, paypal, paypal-ipn

I am having trouble getting Paypal's IPN integrated into my php, i have the following script and it keeps falling through to the default case when a payment is made in the paypal sandbox.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
$request = "cmd=_notify-validate"; 
    foreach ($_POST as $varname => $varvalue){
        $email .= "$varname: $varvalue\n";  
        if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc') and get_magic_quotes_gpc()){  
            $varvalue = urlencode(stripslashes($varvalue)); 
        }
        else { 
            $value = urlencode($value); 
        } 
        $request .= "&$varname=$varvalue"; 
    } 
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,"https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr");
    //curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,"https://www.paypal.com");
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$request);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,false);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    switch($result){
        case "VERIFIED":
                    mail('test@test.com','worked','worked');
            break;
        case "INVALID":
            mail('test@test.com','invaild','invaild');
            break;
        default:
            mail('test@test.com','failed','failed');
    }
```

if i email myself $result it is just blank.

EDIT: I found out it is a server-side issue with my LAMP but am unsure of how to fix it.

Note: i do have curl installed on the server, but i am not sure if it is configured properly.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest doing some debugging using var_dump and Paypal's test tool located here: https://developer.paypal.com/cgi-bin/devscr?cmd=_ipn-link-session

I can understand it becomes difficult and time consuming when working with Third Party Services.

It may be worth simply grabbing the POST data, serializing it and applying it to a variable so you can test without PayPal hitting your callback.

I'd do something like this initially to grab the PayPal POST.

```
<?php
   file_put_contents(serialize($_POST), 'post.log');
   //Now you have the post request serialized we can grab the contents and apply it to a variable for fast testing.
?>
```

Start of your code:

```
<?php
    $_POST = unserialize(file_get_content('post.log'));
    //Now you can execute the script via command line or within your browser without requiring PayPal's testing tool. Use var_dump to investigate what's the issue.
    $request = "cmd=_notify-validate"; 
    foreach ($_POST as $varname => $varvalue){
        $email .= "$varname: $varvalue\n";  
        if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc') and get_magic_quotes_gpc()){  
            $varvalue = urlencode(stripslashes($varvalue)); 
        }
        else { 
            $value = urlencode($value); 
        } 
        $request .= "&$varname=$varvalue"; 
    }
?>
```

NOW: This is a bit more effective and efficient when it comes to testing. In your example you were emailing yourself, but not including $result anywhere within the body of the mail function.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

PayPal's IPN example uses fsock, although CURL is more effective and easier to use. Also there have been some recent issues with PayPal's sandbox changing. https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/Selling-on-your-website/IPN-response-problem/m-p/519862/message-uid/519862#U519862

Also : To determine what the main cause is, as you've said it appears to be your LAMP stack. Check your logs directory (generally /var/log/) generally from their you'll be able to pinpoint what's failing.

Comment: I solved the problem, looks like paypal was having problems communicating via SSL to my server i put in the following line and it worked:

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);